# Are there any non-trivial sequences which satisfy these conditions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that
$$a_1=a_2=a_3=0$$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}a_i \ \ ({}^{\forall}n\in\mathbb{N})$$
$$a_{n+1}\geq a_n-1 \ \ ({}^{\forall}n\in\mathbb{N}).$$
Are there any sequences other than $a_n=0 \ \ ({}^{\forall}n\in\mathbb{N})$ that satisfy these conditions?

It seems that somehow 'oscillation' becomes large when satisfying the first and second conditions, then such sequences violate the third condition. Therefore, I suspect there are no non-trivial sequences, but I have not figure out how to show this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sort of discrete Laplacian problem. This version is well-known:

> At every point of the plane with integer coordinates a real number is
>   written. Every number is the average of the four adjacent numbers in
>   the north, south, east and west directions. If the written numbers are
>   bounded in absolute value, they are all the same number.

In your case the number $a_n$ is not the average of a fixed amount of neighbours and the constraint "bounded" is replaced by the milder "with a sublinear growth", but the spirit should be the same: it is enough to prove that any sequence fulfilling $a_n=\frac{1}{2n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}a_k$ (we may call them *pseudo-harmonic*) oscillates too fast at some point, and to use the generating functions machinery should be a good way to go. Of course we have:
$$ (2n+1)a_{n+1}-(2n-1)a_n = a_{2n+1}+a_{2n} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.